# How to display tooltip of a disabled materialized button

Tags: html, css, materialize

I tried using solution on the web but can't get working I want to display tooltip of a disabled button. I use materialized css.

Here is my html of button:-

```
<div class="input-field col s7">
<button id="btn" class="btn blue-grey tooltipped" data-tooltip="Button will be Enabled after file upload" disabled>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't enable the tooltip for the disabled `<button>` or `<a>`, but you can do a trick and wrap your button inside a `<span>` then add the tooltip to that `<span>` element instead of `<button>` itself. So you have to manage the `<span>` tooltip in *enabling/disable* events.

So your code should be something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltipped");
  var instances = M.Tooltip.init(elems);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-field col s7">
  <span class="tooltipped" data-tooltip="Button will be Enabled after file upload">
    <button id="btn" class="btn blue-grey" disabled>Submit</button>
  </span>
</div>
```